# Error every time the destructor is called

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I got a weird message everytime the destructor is called. Since one of my private variable is dynamic allocated array (`int *member;`), I write the destructor like this:

```
ClassSet::~ClassSet(){delete []member;}
```

Everytime the destructor for `ClassSet` is called, I got an error message:

> Windows has triggered a breakpoint in Hw1.exe.
>
> This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in Hw1.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
>
> This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while Hw1.exe has focus.

entire class:

```
class ClassSet
{
  public:
    ClassSet(int n = DEFAULT_MAX_ITEMS);
ClassSet(const ClassSet& other);
ClassSet &operator=(const ClassSet& other);
~ClassSet();
  private:
    int size;
int *member;
 };

ClassSet::ClassSet(int n){
   size = n;
   member = new int[n];
}

ClassSet::ClassSet(const ClassSet& other){
    int i = 0;
    this->size = other.size;
member = new int [capacity];
while (i<size)
{
    this->member[i] = other.member[i];
    i++;
}
 }

 Multiset& Multiset::operator=(const Multiset &other)
 {
    if (&other == this){return *this;}
this->size = other.size;
int i = 0;
    delete [] member;
    member = new int[size];
while (i<other.size)
{
    this->member[i] = other.member[i];
    i++;
}
return *this;
}
```

Any idea what's wrong with this destructor?

Comment: Let's see the declaration of `member`

Comment: [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: Show us the entire class.

Comment: and also, how it is allocated/created.

Comment: Show us how you initialize `member` and where you allocate it. Better yet, as @NPE said, show us the entire class.

Comment: Looks like a double `delete` is the problem.

Comment: If member is not an array, you should just delete member, not using []:s, you only need to use delete if you used member = new foo(); in the constructor (or in other way created it using memory on the heap)

Comment: no way this is too localized. This happens to everybody. Could very likely be a dup though.

Answer (score 4):

You failed to implement (or you have implemented incorrectly) one of `ClassSet::ClassSet(const ClassSet&)` or `ClassSet::operator=(const ClassSet&)`.

In other words, you have violated the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

The best solution, however, is likely **not** to implement them, but rather to change how you allocate space for your dynamic array. Instead of using `new[]` and `delete[]`, try replacing that member with a `std::vector<>`.

Comment: I think I implement the copy constructor and operator= correctly. because when I assign "ClassSet aaa = b or ClassSet aaa; aaa=b" when I change an element in aaa, it does not change any element in b.

Comment: If you have implemented those correctly, then my theory is wrong. Regardless, I recommend that you do not use `new[]` directly, but use `std::vector<int>` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Heap corruption is often something detected after-the-fact. It may have to do with your destructor, or as I've seen, can likely happen well before the heap access the error occurs at.

Basically "Heap corruption detected" simply means that on a given access of the heap, Windows decided that the current state of the heap was inconsistent/invalid. Something went bad a while earlier.

These bugs can be really hard to track down. One common cause of heap corruption though is **double deletion** you deleted something twice inadvertently. This can point at deeper issues with how your data is copied around your code and your design.

This can happen, as others have said, when you don't have an appropriate copy constructor/assignment operator that copies dynamic memory. The "copy" deletes your memory, then the initial class deletes again, causing a double delete.

Comment: Although, `delete` is silent over null pointers, so that way you won't spot potential double deletes.

Comment: setting to NULL just hides issues since you shouldn't be calling delete on something twice to begin with

Comment: @JesusRamos: not setting NULL just hides the issue that you access members after deletion.  There's arguments both ways, both ways hide some information.

Comment: @MooingDuck And for everything else there's Valgrind :P

Comment: @JesusRamos yeah in this case you guys are absolutely correct. Corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you've posted you actual code, then I think the problem is here:

```
ClassSet::ClassSet(const ClassSet& other){
    int i = 0;
    this->size = other.size;
    member = new int [capacity];  // <--- what is capacity?
    while (i<size)
    {
        this->member[i] = other.member[i];
        i++;
    }
}
```

You're sizing the copied array based on something named `capacity` which doesn't have any obvious relationship to `other.size`.  If `capacity` is smaller than `size` the loop that copies elements will corrupt the heap.

Assuming that this is an academic exercise, once you solve this problem you should look into the [copy/swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) that used for classes like these to ensure exception safety.

If this isn't an academic exercise, then you should be looking at `std::vector` or other containers that are provided in libraries.

Comment: capacity is a global constant (the number of element that the array member can have). size it the number element in the array that have been filled by user (not some random number that fill the array when the array is initiated)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is quite common. The default copy constructor is equivalent to

```
ClassSet(const ClassSet& other) {
    size = other.size;
    member = other.member;
}
```

The problem with this is that when an instance `ClassSet` is copied, both the original instance and the new instance hold a raw pointer to `member`. Both destructors will free `member`, causing the double free problem you are seeing.

For example,

```
{
    ClassSet a
    ClassSet b(a); // assert(b.member == a.member)
} // At this point, both a and b will free the same pointer.
```

You can mitigate this by not allowing copying, or moving the pointer instead of copying.

Comment: am not using the default copy constructor and default operator =
I think I implement the copy constructor and operator= correctly. because when I assign "ClassSet aaa = b or ClassSet aaa; aaa=b" when I change an element in aaa, it does not change any element in b.

Comment: @user1988385 Post it and we can check.